# progress bar with reference line using css and html

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I am trying to achieve  a similar UI as shown in the image link: https://goo.gl/photos/4dNFyq8a3nESQj2g9 . 
[image]
It is not a normal progress bar. I need to add a reference data line, the name for reference line (in the picture it is "TODAY") and the text inside the progress bar. Could anyone help me with this? I only can find a normal progress bar and I fails to add the reference data line & reference line text to it :(

I have my progress bar working, but I do not know how to add reference line and reference text.

```
#progress {
 width: 500px;   
 border: 1px solid black;
 position: relative;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

#percent {
 position: absolute;   
 left: 10px;
 color: white;
}

#bar {
 height: 20px;
 background-color: green;
 width: 30%;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px
}

<div id="progress">
    <span id="percent">30%</span>
    <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show us something you've tried? Have you got a progress bar working?

Comment: yes, added my attempt.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.progress {
    width: 400px;
}
.progress header span {
    color: #666;
    float: right;
}
.progress .bar {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.progress .bar .percent {
    color: white;
    background-color: #0c0;
    width: 70%;
}
.progress .bar .ref {
    position: absolute;
    left: 80%;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
.progress .bar .ref:before {
    content: attr(data-ref);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    left: -50px;
    top: 100%;
    color: #888;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
    <header><b>April 2015</b><span>$350 Left</span></header>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="percent">$950 of $1,300</div>
        <div class="ref" data-ref="TODAY"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```